# In what case would I want to use, int main(int argc, const char * argv[])?

Tags: arguments

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
```

I know that i can obtain the number of arguments from argc and the pointers to arguments from argv. But why would i want to know this? How could I use it in a program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking arguments into a program is a common way to make it possible to change how the program will run. Anytime you run a program and put additional flags after it, this is how they are reading those flags.

For instance,

`main -a "hello world"`

In this case, -a and "hello world" are both arguments that you would need to read using that array and argument count. What you would want to do with them and what kinds of arguments you think would make sense is entirely up to you.